# increase and decrease letter

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var letterbox = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I",];

var counter = 0;

  $(".plusbtn").click(function(){

    if(counter >= letterbox.length - 1){
        counter = -1;
    }

    counter++;

    $(".ux--wrapper").empty();
    $(".ux--wrapper").append("<p>"+letterbox[counter]+"</p>");
  });

  $(".minbtn").click(function(){
      if(counter <= 0){
        counter = letterbox.length;
        }

    counter--;
    $(".ux--wrapper").empty();
    $(".ux--wrapper").append("<p>"+letterbox[counter]+"</p>");
  });
```

my intention the letter start at A and when you press plus it keep increase to B , c , D and so on. when you press min it decrease , but because the number start at 0 , so i have some problem at plusing i have to use -1 to make it right , but i feel i am doing wrong.

i am i doing the right way here ? can you make it more low risky ? i feel like my code is risky

[Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/r9cc2c4r/1/)

Comment: This looks like a perfectly appropriate way to go about the problem at hand. Your current code even handles going left from A, so it seems pretty good to me. The only things I would change are not ending the array with a comma, and using `.innerHTML` instead of emptying and appending to the element every time  :)

Comment: You can manipulate the charcodes and transform them into string, when needed, with `String.fromCharCode`. So `"A"` has a charCode of `65`, meaning `String.fromCharCode(65)` would result in `"A"`.

Comment: the only thing that is risky here is the fact that counter is accessible from anywhere. for that you could wrap your code inside self instantiating function. your code is perfectly fine (except the comma mentioned above)

Comment: Also `"B"` char has a charCode of 66, `"C"` – 67 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is error free, but it can be simplified in multiple ways. Here is one of them:

```
var letterbox = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I",];

var counter = 0;

function update_counter(inc)
{
    counter = (counter + inc + letterbox.length) % letterbox.length;
    $(".ux--wrapper").empty().append("<p>"+letterbox[counter]+"</p>");
}

$(".plusbtn").click(function() { update_counter(1) });
$(".minbtn").click(function() { update_counter(-1) });
```

By creating a function that handles the common part to execute between the two buttons, you greatly reduces the code size.

Note the double use of `letterbox.length` inside the modulo operation: it lets you handle negative increments (considering that this increment is `-1`, or at least greater than `-letterbox.length`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulo (similar to remainder) operator, `%`, and `data-increment` attributes on each button to reduce the number of event listeners necessary and make your code more readable:

```js
var letters = 'ABCDEFGHI'.split('')
var counter = 0

var output = $('.ux--wrapper p')[0]

$('.plusbtn, .minbtn').click(function() {

  counter += +$(this).data('increment')

  if (counter < 0) counter += letters.length
  else counter %= letters.length

  output.textContent = letters[counter]
})
```

```css
.minbtn,
.plusbtn {
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.ux--wrapper {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="minbtn" data-increment="-1">-</button>
<div class="ux--wrapper">
  <p>A</p>
</div>
<button class="plusbtn" data-increment="+1">+</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var letterbox = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I",];

var counter = 0;

$(".plusbtn").click(function(){
    if(counter < letterbox.length){
        counter++;
    } else {
        counter = 0;
    }
    displayCounter();
});

function displayCounter() {
    $(".ux--wrapper").empty();
    $(".ux--wrapper").append("<p>"+letterbox[counter]+"</p>");
});

$(".minbtn").click(function(){
    if(counter > 0){
        counter--;
    } else {
        counter = letterbox.length;
    }
    displayCounter();
});
```